# How do I correctly define my variables?

Tags: function, python-3.x, variables

So I have defined a function which generates a random n x m matrix of binary integers called `random_matrix`. For the purposes of this I am only interested in generating binary vectors i.e. matrices of dimension n x 1. These are represented by lists. I have also defined a function which takes an input vector of binary integers and outputs a vector with bit flips with given percentage of occurence called `bf_2`.

Now what I want is Alice to generate a random input vector, Bob to have an identical vector and Eve to have a bit flipped version of Alice's vector. So I used the code below:

```
import functions_module as fm

input_length = int(input('What is the length of the input string?'))
error = int(input('What is the percentage error in the string received by Eve?'))

Alice = fm.random_matrix(input_length,1)
Bob = Alice
Eve = fm.bf_2(Alice,error)

print(Alice)
print(Bob)
print(Eve)
```

However this gives identical outputs for Alice, Bob and Eve which is not what I want. It has something to do with the way I am defining my variables Alice, Bob and Eve. Any help would be much appreciated! I want something that would output

```
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,0]
```

I have given my bit flip code below.

```
def bf_2(bit_string,percentage_error):

    """Bit flips the input string for a given percentage of occurence"""

    from random import randint

    bits = bit_string

    for i in range(0,len(bits)):
        r = randint(1,100)
        if r <= percentage_error:
            if bits[i] == 0:
                bits[i] = 1
            else:
                bits[i] = 0

    return bits
```

Comment: `Alice` and `Bob` are the same list. Use `Bob = Alice[:]` to make `Bob` a copy of `Alice` rather than the same object.

Comment: Also, `bf_2()` isn't doing what you think, for a similar reason - `bits` ***is*** `bit_string`, and you're mutating it inside the function.

Comment: See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder for more on this.

Comment: @Zero Why leave an answer in the comments? You have a perfectly valid answer there with backing references.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart partly because I hadn't expected to go further than the first comment (which is a bit sparse for an answer) until I'd looked properly at `bf_2()`, and partly because it's almost certainly a duplicate (which I'd have gone looking for if your answer hadn't shown up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bob = Alice
```

This doesnt do what you probably are expecting. Now you have two *names* referring to the same *object*. Modifications using either variable will be visible to both variable (because they are thesame thing.)

You need to *copy* the object. Using [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) is generally the safest way to do so. It copies not only the given object, but also all of the objects it refers to, ensuring that you don't end up with an inner reference being shared between the copied top-level objects.

```
import copy
Bob = copy.deepcopy(Alice)
```